# Best place to persist large chunks of plain text

Tags: database, persistence

I have an application that allows the user to create/edit several chunks of HTML. Currently I'm persisting this data on a database, but I believe that it's not the best solution for two reasons:

- I never query the data
- The database starts to run slow very quickly (since there are hundreds of megabytes of plain text).

My first guess is that it's better to persist it on the filesystem (with gzip), and store some identification on the database. Are there solutions better than this one?

Comment: First question is probably a bit silly- but if you never query the data, why are you persisting it?

Comment: I never query within the html. It acts like a binary file, where I don't care what's inside of it, I just give it back to the user on screen.

Comment: which database are you using? MySQL should have no problems with hundreds of megabytes of data.

Comment: I'm using MySQL. It's very slow to query anything, even if the fields are indexed. I'm talking about 10k rows, which is not that big.